# Codeigniter run query before a update

Tags: database, codeigniter

I have to run a query after every update and I want to know if there is a way to automate a `$this->db->query()` before every `$this->db->update()`

I'm using it for log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write your own function in the file `core/MY_Model.php` to do that:

```
function queryThenUpdate($query,$update)
{
   $query = $this->db->query($query);
   //use as you need $query
   $this->db->update($update['table'],$update['data']);
}
```

where:

1. `$query` is your actual query: `SELECT * FROM ...`
2. `$update` is an array of two elements `$update['table']` is the table to update and `$update['data']` is the updating data as specified on codeigniter active record's documentation

then make every model extend MY_Model

```
class Your_Model extend MY_Model
```

and every time you need to update something:

```
$this->Your_Model->queryThenUpdate($query,$update)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use codeigniters 'hook'